# A free variable $x$ in $\exists x x<(y\cdot y) \wedge\forall y \neg x\doteq (y+y)$

Tags: logic

Is $x$ a free variable in $\exists x x<(y\cdot y) \wedge\forall y \neg x\doteq (y+y)$?

I'm asking because you can read $\exists x x<(y\cdot y) \wedge\forall y \neg x\doteq (y+y)$ as:

1. $(\exists x x<(y\cdot y) )\wedge (\forall y \neg x\doteq (y+y))$? Or
2. $\exists x (x<(y\cdot y) \wedge\forall y \neg x\doteq (y+y))$?

In case 1 $x$ is free since $x$ is free in $\forall y \neg x\doteq (y+y)$ and in case 2 $x$ is not free.

How to read this? What is the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "standard" conventions in math log regarding the omission of parentheses, based on "precedence" between *connectives*.

Regarding *quantifiers*, the omission of parentheses can cause big troubles.

In Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd ed Harcourt - 2001), page 78, we have :

> $\lnot$, $\forall$, and $\exists$ apply to as little as possible. For example,
>
> > $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ is $(\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, and not $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$.

According to the above convention, the "correct" reading of your formula is 1).

The same convention is used in :

Stephen Cole Kleene, *Mathematical Logic* (1967), page 80 : "The quantifiers acts as unary operators in building formulas, and with our other unary operator $\lnot$ are ranked last under the convention for omitting parentheses."

in Dirk van Dalen, *Logic and Structure* (5th ed - 2013), page 58 : "We agree that quantifiers bind more strongly than binary connectives."

and in :

George Tourlakis, *Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 1 : Mathematical Logic* (2003), page 17 : "To minimize the use of brackets in the metanotation we adopt standard priorities of connectives: $\forall$, $\exists$, and $\lnot$ have the highest".

But a good advice is : "do not save ink !"

Answer (score 1):

In logic, there is no generally accepted precedence rule for determining how missing parentheses should be inserted.   The "formula" that you started with is simply not a well-formed formula.